# Codeigniter ajax call does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

For example if I click 'vote up' button it successfully adds vote for the first post and displays the result in span element with class="rate_votes", but it also displays the same result in all the span elements with same class because of the following line:

$(".rate_votes").text(rate); //

How can I avoid that?
If I use

$(this).text(rate); //

it will not work properly because it does not know which span element to select. Could you help me please.

Here is my view:

```
<div>
          <?php                                      
                 foreach($results as $row){
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $rate = $row['rate'];                   
          ?> 
   <div>
   <?php 
   $data = array(
    'name' => $id,
    'class' => 'rate',    
    'content' => 'Vote Up'
   );
   echo form_button($data);
   ?>

  <span class="rate_votes" >
  <?php echo $rate; ?>
  </span>

   </div>   

 </div>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".rate").click(function(){
            var self = this;
            $(self).attr("disabled", true);
            var id_like = $(self).attr("name");


            $.post('filter/get_rate', { id_like: id_like }, function (data) {

                var my_obj = data;        
                $.each(my_obj, function (i) {

                   var rate = my_obj[i].rate;

                   $(".rate_votes").text(rate); //     
                   $(self).text("Voted!");   
                 });        

                }, "json");  
            });     

});
```

Comment: have you verified this ? Try firebug to monitor the ajax calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with codeigniter :)

You bind the click event to an ID, `#rate` but that ID appears multiple times.

`$data = array(
    'name' => $id,
    'id' => 'rate',

    'content' => 'Vote Up'
   );
   echo form_button($data);`

use a class instead.

When you select an ID that appears multiple times, only the first one is selected, thus only the first button works.

**EDIT**
Your comment sounds a bit strange, Given this code for example :
**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$('.foo').click(function() { $(this).remove() });
```

The above code only removes the specific div being clicked, That is the event is only fired once and for that element only.

Doublecheck your javascript.

Comment: Edited my answer, specifically try changing 

 `$('#rate').attr("disabled", true);  ` to   `$(this).attr("disabled", true); `

Comment: Patrick, I changed the id to class but there is a problem with following lines: $(".rate_votes").text(rate); $('.rate').text("Voted!");

Comment: I don't see that ID anywhere in code you posted, Read the other answer posted aswell.

Comment: you can see in my view that i have a span element where i display the votes. After clicking the 'vote_up' button, the text of span element changes thanks to the following line: $(".rate_votes").text(rate); If I use class for span element, it displays the result for the first post on each post with the same class. So how can I avoid that?

Comment: `$('.rate').text("Voted!");` Again, you'll want to use `this` instead of the selector, However since that line of code is within a `POST` request, `this` is out of context. try adding another variable at the beginning, something like `var self = this;`, then you can reference `self` all over the function with the correct `context`.

Comment: that's great! thanks Patrick. The problem is almost solved but there is still one issue left. I have just edited my question. Could you have a look on it please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55629/discussion-between-tprodeveloper-and-patrick).

Answer (score 3):

You have used:

```
$("#rate").click(function(){...})
```

Here `"#rate"` is an `id` and an `id` must be unique, use `class` like `.rate`. If you have multiple elements with same `id` on the page then only the first element of the page will be counted. So the following code is registering the click handler only on the first element with id `rate`:

```
$("#rate").click(function(){
    //...
});
```

Give your elements a class instead, for example:

```
<button class='rate'>Rate</button>
<button class='rate'>Rate</button>
```

So this code will work on every button click:

```
$(".rate").click(function(){
    var id_like = $(this).attr("name");

    $(this).attr("disabled", true); // disables the current button
    $('.rate').attr("disabled", true); // disable all the buttons with class rate

    //...
});
```